# Spring Data JPA Page and JSON with Gson

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I use spring mvc with xml configuration with dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Convert to JSON. But with Spring data JPA Page  the result is empty:
`{}`. With Repository:

```
@Repository("personRepository")
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {

    Page<Person> findAll(Pageable pageable);

}
```

and Controller:

```
@RestController
public class ApiController {

    @Autowired
    PersonService personService;

    @GetMapping(value = {"/api/person/getpage"}, produces = {"application/json"})
    public Page<Person> getPerson() {
        return personService.findAll(new PageRequest(0, 10));
    }
}
```

Can anybody show me how to return the correct data to the format:

```
{ "totalPages":501,
"totalElements":5001,
"size":10,
"content":[{"id":1,"firstName":"Joe","lastName":"Doe"}, 
           {"id":2,"firstName":"Mich","lastName":"Jogger"}, 
           {"id":3,"firstName":"Santa","lastName":"Close"}, ...],
"number":0,
"numberOfElements":10,
"sort":null,
"last":false,
"first":true}
```

I

Comment: U need switch your repository interface to PagingAndSortingRepository or JpaRepository, which have build-in Page<Person> findAll(Pageable pageable);

Comment: I have tried to switch your repository interface to PagingAndSortingRepository or JpaRepository. But the result is still: {}

Answer (score -1):

you have to change your return type to `List<Person>` in controller. i can see 5001 records available in db. sample controller code ,

```
@GetMapping(value = {"/api/person/getpage"}, produces = {"application/json"})
public List<Person> getPerson() {
    Page<Person> pagePersonList = personService.findAll(new PageRequest(0, 10));
    List<Person> personList = pagePersonList.getContent();
    return personList;
}
```

let me know if any have any problems or queries.

Comment: I want to return the Page <Person> type to use in smart-table with the angularjs for paging.

Comment: i'm not familiar with angular/smart table if you don't want to change your return type create one custom entity with same signature and put that personList in content using setter and use it in angular